# Random posts that always include a particular post?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts

How can I always include a post/ page in the random result?

For instance, I always want to get 3 items only from my articles. But I want the result always has the article with `page order` 1:

```
    $parent = $post->ID;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $query_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'orderby'   => 'rand',
      'post_parent' => $parent,
      'paged' => $paged
    );

    // create a new instance of WP_Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

So the result will be:

1, 2, 3, or 2, 1, 4, or 4, 2, 1

Is it possible? Does WordPress has any defaults for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code::

post__in (array) - use post ids. Specify posts to retrieve. ATTENTION If you use sticky posts, they will be included (prepended!) in the posts you retrieve whether you want it or not.

```
<?php
    $parent = $post->ID;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $query_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_in' => array('post_id_to_include'),
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'orderby'   => 'rand',
      'post_parent' => $parent,
      'paged' => $paged
    );

   // create a new instance of WP_Query
   $wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
?>
```

Comment: thanks. how can i find the post id by `page order`?

Comment: You want result in exact pattern `1, 2, 3, or 2, 1, 4, or 4, 2, 1`

Comment: yes in all of these patterns. as long as 1 is in the result. then randomise them.

Comment: I found the key myself now. but `'post_in' => array('post_id_to_include'),` does not work.

Comment: @BlueSuiter post_in should be post__in with two underscores, not one - in description its right but in code its wrong

Comment: Okay, thank you.